# Google experiments A/B test Variant links don't work

Tags: google-analytics, google-experiments

I want to test two landing pages in Google experiments,
However each time I run the test all of the links on the variant B page redirect back to variant B rather than going to the correct URL. The original page is working as it should.

Any ideas as to why this might be happening?

Answer (score 0):

The experiment javascript code should only be put in he 'original' variant. Not on all pages, otherwise links in the variant will keep redirecting to itself.